# Getting Error Code: 8155 No column was specified for column 2 of 'pol' in SQL server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

`Select a.className1
     , a.classNumber
     , b.firstName + b.lastName 
     , cl.status AS 'Active'
From a 
Left Join cl
     on a.id = cl.id
Left Join (Select a.id, count(b.teachCode) 
           from a
           Left join b
                on a.id = b.id
           Group by a.id) tt 
     On tt.id = a.id`

I have above code, it return error code 8155.I tried to debug it, but I couldn't figure out what went wrong.

Comment: 1) This query has no table/view/table valued function/alias named `pol`. Are you sure this is the query which generates this error ? 2) First, you should assign an alias for expression `count(b.teachCode)`: `count(b.teachCode) AS numOfTeachers`. 2) Second, you could assign, also, an alias to `b.firstName + b.lastName`: `b.firstName + b.lastName  AS fullName`.

Comment: @baciyan: Just FYI, you *don't have to* use `count` merely because you are using `group by`. And indeed you don't seem to need to use it as you aren't referencing the count value anywhere in your query (unless it was posted incomplete, of course).

Comment: Also, why did you tag your question as `mysql`? Is it about MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing the subquery, if count is not used in the output

You need to join with table b again
As subquery doesn't return columns from b

```
  Select a.className1 ,   
            a.classNumber , 
            b.firstName + b.lastName , 
            cl.status AS 'Active' 
  From a 
  Left Join cl on a.id = cl.id 
  Left join b on a.id =b.id -> this is needed
  Left Join (Select a.id, 
                         count(b.teachCode)   As teachcode  
                  from a 
                  Left join b 
                  on a.id = b.id 
                  Group by a.id) tt 
  On tt.id = a.id
```

Comment: Still return the same error. I use count because I need to use Group by to eliminate redundant value.

Comment: Can you share table schema and sample data and sample output?